# Location retrieved is always null

Tags: android, android-studio, google-api

I am learning location services in Android via this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nwdwzQhutdo

I have all the right code based on the video but the location is always null. I can't seem to figure out why that is happening.

OUTPUT: `Location could not be detected. Try again later.`

**CODE**

```
public void onCreate() {
    getLocation();
    locationButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (null != mGoogleApiClient && mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
                try {
                    Location location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
                    if (location != null) {
                        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Double.toString(location.getLatitude()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        toast.show();
                    } else {
                        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Location could not be detected. Try again later.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        toast.show();
                    }
                } catch(SecurityException e) {
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ERROR: Could not detect location. Please check location settings.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    toast.show();
                }
            } else {
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error: Not connected to google play services", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();
            }
        }
    });
}

private void getLocation() {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addConnectionCallbacks(this).addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).addApi(LocationServices.API).build();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}
```

Comment: Which toast is showing?

Comment: @DanielNugent   Location could not be detected. Try again later.

Comment: Can you post your full code? Especially `mGoogleApiClient`

Comment: @Egek92 It is already there at the bottom of the pasted code.

Comment: @Newbie Check my answer below, i think you are not asking permission on run time.